# Send Free SMS from C#.NET Windows Application

Tags: c#, sms

So Yet another SMS question :-)

I researched, but could not find a solution to my requirements.

I do not have a GSM modem, nor can I pay for any Third-Party software for sending SMS. Also I spent quiet some time learning SMS gateways. But when I experimented with it, it failed.eg: I emailed number@textin.in but no message was received at the receiver's side!

The application I am building takes up phone-numbers from a database and sends a different SMS to each number depending on certain condition.

Being a student, I just have to look for Free websites like 
 http://site3.way2sms.com/content/index.html and others,but don't know how to use them programatically!

So my straightforward question is : "How can I send SMS using just the internet?".
My SMS recipients will all be resident in India. And language is C# using Visual Studio 2010.

Please Help......

Comment: You may want to ask how to call APIs of certain Web Based SMS Server. You wont get sufficient answer from a question that requires broad discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use web requests !

Here is a great examples of Web requesets usage : [WebResourceProvider](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/WebResourceProviderDotNet.aspx)  using C#

All you need is just inspect web portal structure and run your web bot. There could be Usual bot's trouble with Captcha but you can google solutions where you can get media (picture of captcha) to your application. (I think that is another question)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to find an SMS provider that provides an API for you to access programatically.

Unfortunately, I don't think you will be able to find any provider that will let you send large amount of texts free.

Some of the providers discussed here may be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238579/free-sms-api